# Why animal eyes see the spectrum from red to violet?

Tags: visible-light, vision, biology

Maybe this would not be proper question on physics stack exchange, but it originated from physics book so I'll post it here anyway. I have much interest in color recognition evolution.
I'm studying the famous Jackson E&M book, and it has a following sentence; (on p.314 of 3rd Ed.)

'the reader may meditate on the fundamental question of biological evolution on this water-soaked planet, of why animal eyes see the spectrum from red to violet and of why the grass is green.', 
with the graph of absorption coefficient for liquid water vs. freq.

The graph is same as the following.
https://www.britannica.com/science/absorption-coefficient

I can see that animals have evolved in the way to exploit the water-transparent frequency, but I'm not sure how that relates to the color recognition. So the human evolved to see grass as green, and use colors from red to violet (using RGB cones). Color itself is invention of animals, nothing inherent in nature. But why it had to be that way? In my first thought, human could have different cone cells, and could feel grass as blue, could used different primary colors. (I cannot imagine that because my world is RGB world but I think thats possible)

Jackson seems to imply that there is a reason that it has to be this way, but I'm cannot see the reasoning. Maybe was he just suggesting to think?

Comment: The quote you provided doesn't seem to imply anything about color recognition. "Why the grass is green" refers to the fact that chlorophyll in grass (and other plants) evolved to preferentially absorb red and violet light. It's a statement about the absorption spectrum of a particular molecule, independent of whether certain animals _see_ it as being green.

Comment: @probably_someone I'm sorry, then why did plants evolve to absorb red and violet light?

Comment: Well, that's a different question entirely. This site seems to answer it: http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=500. Basically, it's because absorbing too much energy would kill the plant, so the absorption spectrum needs to be somewhat far away from the peak of the Sun's emission spectrum (which is in the vicinity of green light).

Comment: As far as "why animals see the spectrum from red to violet," first of all, not all animals do (bees can see into the ultraviolet, and mantis shrimp have a ridiculous amount of spectral range), and second, because that's where most of the Sun's light is emitted (after being filtered by the atmosphere).

Comment: And many animals don’t have color vision, only black and white... Hence why hot pink camo works for deer hunting.

Comment: I know that animal vision is all diffrent to human, but that's exactly the point what confuses me. Jackson specifically wrote 'red to violet', and 'green' . So do you think that when Jackson wrote these color names, he just meant the freq. of them, not their meaning, and also considering the biological fact that plants prefer longer wavelength which is not physics at all? It seems weird to me...

Comment: @Septacle - That's ignorant physicists for ya. Evolution has no goal. It finds something that works good enough. The precursors to plants found a chemical that suboptimally absorbed in the red and blue/violet but reflected green (where the Sun's light is most intense). This happenstance happened to be successful, enabling the precursor to pass its genes to its offspring, and ultimately to green grass. Mammalian eyes are also quite suboptimal, but they work, at least good enough.

Comment: @DavidHammen I see your point dimly. My confusion was: Red was not red before animal evolved red vision, in the similar way sweet taste is sweet because it helped animals to store energies. So it's kind of silly thing to say 'sweet things are good for storing energy', because though it's true it's cause/effect reversed. In the same way, it's kind of silly to say grass is green because grass is not green inherently, but human evolved to see grass as green. Only case that 'grass is green' makes sense is when there is no other term to describe light which have freq. around 500nm.

Comment: So I was confused Jacskson used color names explicitly in evolutionary context. My understanding is: Jackson just used the color names just to denote the freq. And you said evolution has no goal, so my understanding is, there could be other color combination human could adopt but RGB system is what we evolved, and there is nothing special about it. Am I right?

Comment: (1) Some people see 4 colors, not just 3 RGB. (2) The origin of species is unknown. Most likely a quantum evolution, not just random mutations. (3) No one here has commented on the linked graph, a remarkable coincidence that water passes exactly the spectral peak of the sunlight. (4) "Red" or "green" are subjective labels. You have no idea how I see the green color.  (5) The energy efficiency of plants and animals is mind blowing. Not a "good enough" coincidence at all. (6) What exactly is your question?

Comment: @safesphere (6) How does the graph explain grass is green.

Comment: Grass is green and blood is red for the same reason copper roofs are green while iron roofs are (rusty) red. Chlorofil and hemoglobin essentially are the same protein with an atom of copper in the former replaced by an atom of iron in the latter. Plants don't reflect all green light, just a small portion of it. There is no energy significance to grass being green nor there is any relation of the grass color to the graph. It is a coincidence that leaves reflect a bit more green in the middle of the spectrum . Flowers don't. I'd say the primary purpose of the colors is for the beauty.